# Can I throw an unmanaged exception for testing?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write some code to wrap a c++ library that throws unmanaged exceptions.

Just for testing purposes, is it possible to generate an unmanaged exception from c# code without having to create a fake c++ library standin?

Comment: `throw new Exception()`? or am I not understanding your question

Comment: @Jamie Taylor Sangerman unmanaged, not managed.

Comment: @Jamie Taylor Sangerman  Generally all exceptions thrown by c# are managed. The exceptions thrown by this c++ library are unmanaged (and so not caught by c#'s try/catch blocks, or at least so I'm told). I'm wondering if there is a way to throw an UNMANAGED exception from C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The C# Programming Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/how-to-catch-a-non-cls-exception) states that "In C# you cannot throw non-CLS exceptions". This means you can only throw exceptions deriving from the Exception class, i.e. managed exceptions. You'll have to create a c++ library standin.

Incidentally, the same page also explains how to catch such exceptions. However, this only applies when the c++ code in question is actually throwing an exception - if it's an access violation this will be a Corrupted State Exception which cannot be caught, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/clr-inside-out-handling-corrupted-state-exceptions#id0070035) for more.